# Model Formulae. correct model?

Tags: r, regression

I'm trying to build the following model in R, however I'm quite confused about the model formulae to use to include an interaction (x1 and x2)

$Y_{}=a+b*x_1+cx_2+d(x_1*x_2)$

this intuitive formula seems to be wrong model:

```
y~x1+x2+(x1*x2)
```

is this the appropriate formula?:

```
y~x1*x2 ?
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically, yes.* That formula will enter both main effects and the product term as predictors in your model. So will your first version BTW: compare `lm(y~x1*x2);lm(y~x1+x2+x1*x2)`. For example, using `set.seed(8);x1=rnorm(99);x2=rnorm(99);y=rnorm(99)`, either way the equation is: $$\hat Y=-.16-.02x_1-.08x_2+.09(x_1\times x_2)$$

If for some (probably improper) reason you wanted only the interaction term, you'd use `x1:x2` – note this is how the interaction term is labeled in the output, not as `x1*x2`.

---

* You might want to `scale` your predictors to remove nonessential multicollinearity if you're interested in the standard errors of your regression coefficents or other associated statistics (including $t$s and $p$s for your predictors). This is unnecessary for the interaction term though; it only changes standard errors for the main effects. If you use `y~scale(x1,T,F)*scale(x2,T,F)`, this will mean-center `x1` and `x2` but not divide by the standard deviation, thus preserving your units of measurement. If you use `y~scale(x1)*scale(x2)`, this will standardize `x1` and `x2` to the scale of [$Z$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_score). Either works for controlling nonessential multicollinearity, but neither removes essential multicollinearity. For more on that, see the following reference:

<sup>Dalal, D. K., & Zickar, M. J. (2012). Some common myths about centering predictor variables in moderated multiple regression and polynomial regression. *Organizational Research Methods, 15*(3), 339–362. Retrieved from https://umdrive.memphis.edu/dsherrll/public/SCMS8540/Dalal%20%26%20Zickar-2012.pdf.</sup>

Comment: thank you for your extensive answer.  I'm probably gonna use a deflator anyway to reduce size effects, however as you mentioned scaling would also influence the interaction (where scaling is not necessary as i understand you). how can you circumvent this? And thank you for introducing the scale function. i was not aware of this yet.

Comment: Centering *doesn't* influence the interaction. Standardizing (mean-centering and dividing by the *SD*) will change the scale of the interaction's regression coefficient (not the size, mind you; it just removes the units of measurement and places the coefficient on the scale of $\rho$), but won't change its *SE* or NHST statistics.